# Integer Programming Constraints - Min/Max Days Between Deliveries

Tags: modeling, integer-programming

I'm starting a consulting project for a client who manufacturers perishable food.  They want to optimize their delivery schedule to each of their DSD (Direct Store Delivery) customers.

For each store, I have binary decision variables that reflect whether I make a delivery to that store on Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, ... Saturday.

e.g.,
x1 = binary, 1 if I make a delivery on Sunday, 0 if I don't
x2 = binary, 1 if I make a delivery on Monday, 0 if I don't
...
x7 = binary, 1 if I make a delivery on Saturday, 0 if I don't

Based upon the store's demand, I may want to deliver 1x weekly, 2x weekly, 3x weekly, or 4x weekly.  I can set that delivery frequency up as a constraint on the sum of the binaries, but I am having trouble with ensuring spacing of delivery days to ensure the perishable food doesn't spoil on the store shelf.

For example, if I am delivering 2x per week, having delivery days that are consecutive or only spaced by one day in between - Tuesday and Wednesday, or Saturday and Monday - shouldn't be allowed.

For 2x weekly deliveries, I'd like there to be a 3 day gap and a 4 day gap between delivery days: e.g., Sunday & Wednesday; or Friday & Monday.

For 3x weekly deliveries, I'd like there to be at most a 3 day gap between delivery days (Monday & Thursday = 3 day gap).  For 4x delivery days, I'd like there to be at most a 2 day gap between delivery days.

I've figured out an (ugly) way to put this constraint together in a 2x weekly delivery schedule, but no idea how to approach for 3x weekly or 4x weekly.  Any help is appreciated.

Also FYI, I haven't actually coded anything at this point, just thinking through how I'd approach the problem with pen & paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are two approaches, neither guaranteed to be ideal.

Method 1: Create a new set of binary variables $y_1,\dots,y_4$ signaling how many deliveries per week (1 to 4). Add the constraints $$y_1 + \dots + y_4 = 1$$and $$x_1 + \dots + x_7 = y_1 + 2y_2 + 3y_3 +4y_4.$$
To enforce your gap rules for two deliveries, add constraints $$x_i + x_{i + 1} + x_{i + 2} \le 3 - 2 y_2$$ for all relevant $i$. To enforce your gap rules for three deliveries, use $$x_i + x_{i + 1} + x_{i + 2} + x_{i + 3} \ge 2f_3.$$ Enforcing gap rules for four deliveries is left to the reader as an exercise.

Method 2: Rather than using your $x_i$ variables, generate all possible delivery schedules for a week (Monday only; Monday and Thursday; Monday Tuesday and Thursday; etc.) and use a binary variable for each one to select which will be used. Only include schedules that meet your gap criteria. If this results in too many binary variables, use either branch-and-price or a column generation heuristic.

Comment: I may use your second method as my first approach.  This will probably allow me more latitude to use tighter or looser constraints on the delivery schedule options available for a given customer.

Comment: I'm approaching it somewhat differently than Method 2.  I still need the `xi` variables because they are used elsewhere to contribute to the objective function.  However I found a way to ensure the `xi` values are connected to a unique delivery schedule using Method 2.

Answer (score 5):

To disallow any given pattern of $0$ and $1$, you can impose "no-good" constraints.  For example, if you want to avoid delivering on both Tuesday and Wednesday, that is, avoid
$$(x_3,x_4)=(1,1),$$
you want to enforce
$$\lnot (x_3 \land x_4).$$
Rewriting in conjunctive normal form yields
$$\lnot x_3 \lor \lnot x_4.$$
So the desired constraint is
$$(1 - x_3) + (1 - x_4) \ge 1,$$
equivalently,
$$x_3+x_4 \le 1.$$

More generally, for any pair $\{i,j\}$ of days that cannot both have a delivery, impose the "conflict" constraint $x_i+x_j \le 1$.  The model in the linked answer [here](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7531/optimize-days-between-work-shift/7532#7532) strengthens these conflict constraints to "clique" constraints.